# Редактирование материала с видеороликом

Tags: ckeditor

При редактировании материала, содержащего видеоролик, добавленный при помощи плагина `youtube`, ролик в редакторе не открывается. В коде страницы такая запись:

```
<img class="cke_iframe" data-cke-realelement="%3Ciframe%20allowfullscreen%3D%22%22%20src%3D%22%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fembed%pa972hums%3Frel%33Bautoplay%3D0%22%20frameborder%3D%220%22%20height%3D%22360%22%20width%3D%22640%22%3E%3C%2Fiframe%3E" data-cke-real-node-type="1" alt="iFrame" title="iFrame" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPABAP///wAAA5BEKAAAALAAAAAABAAEAICRAEAOw==" data-cke-real-element-type="iframe" data-cke-resizable="true" style="width:640px;height:360px;" align=""><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Видео добавляется в HTML5 не в IMG, а в video тэг
Пример:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Rider_BY, это CKEditor добавляет теги. Он вставляет видео при помощи IFrame. На странице просмотра материала видео выглядит правильно, но когда открываешь материал на редактирование - вместо видео просто рамка с таким кодом. Что интересно - если опять сохранить, то в просмотре материала все опять будет хорошо.